# Scraping Websites With Playwright

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, playwright-python

I am trying to scrape tweets from twitter with Playwright.
The problem I am facing is - after I scroll down with "page.mouse.wheel", I can only get the tweets("page.content"), from after the scrolling, it wont select the previous ones(tried using "query_selector_all").
Anyone knows how to solve it?

This is my code:

```
from parsel import Selector
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from playwright.sync_api._generated import Page
import time
import re


def parse_tweets(selector: Selector):
    """
    parse tweets from pages containing tweets like:
    - tweet page
    - search page
    - reply page
    - homepage
    returns list of tweets on the page where 1st tweet is the
    main tweet and the rest are replies
    """
    results = []
    # select all tweets on the page as individual boxes
    # each tweet is stored under <article data-testid="tweet"> box:
    tweets = selector.xpath("//article[@data-testid='tweet']")
    for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
        # using data-testid attribute we can get tweet details:
        found = {
            "text": "".join(tweet.xpath(".//*[@data-testid='tweetText']//text()").getall()),
            "datetime": tweet.xpath(".//time/@datetime").get()

        }
        # main tweet (not a reply):
        if i == 0:
            found["views"] = tweet.xpath('.//span[contains(text(),"Views")]/../preceding-sibling::div//text()').get()
            found["retweets"] = tweet.xpath('.//a[contains(@href,"retweets")]//text()').get()
            found["quote_tweets"] = tweet.xpath('.//a[contains(@href,"retweets/with_comments")]//text()').get()
            found["likes"] = tweet.xpath('.//a[contains(@href,"likes")]//text()').get()
        results.append({k: v for k, v in found.items() if v is not None})
    return results


def scrape_tweet(url: str, page: Page):

    # go to url
    page.goto(url)
    # wait for content to load

    for i in range(2):  # make the range as long as needed
        page.mouse.wheel(0, 15000)
        page.wait_for_timeout(1000)


    page.query_selector_all("//article[@data-testid='tweet']")
    html = page.content()
    selector = Selector(html)
    tweets = parse_tweets(selector)
    return tweets



with sync_playwright() as pw:
    # start browser and open a new tab:
    browser = pw.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080})
    # scrape tweet and replies:
    tweets = scrape_tweet("https://twitter.com/pcrisk?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor", page)
    for d in tweets:
        txt = d['text']
        date = d['datetime']
        txt = re.sub('\n.*', '', txt)
        extensionregex = '(?<=Extension:\s)([^\;]+)'
        extension = re.findall(extensionregex, txt, re.IGNORECASE)  # Capture extension data
        noteregex = '(?<=Ransom note)(.*)'  # Capture note data
        note = re.findall(noteregex, txt)
        ransomnameregex = '.*(?=\s+Ransomware)'
        ransomname = re.findall(ransomnameregex, txt, re.IGNORECASE)  # Capture name data
        varirantregex = '\w+(?=\s+ransomware\sfamily)'
        varirant = re.findall(varirantregex, txt, re.IGNORECASE)  # Capture variant data
        print(date)
    #print(tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when youre calling `page.content()` after scrolling down, the content of the page that is returned only contains the tweets that were loaded prior to scrolling. youll need to scroll down multiple times and wait for the tweets to load before scraping them. This function waits for the first tweet to load before starting to scroll down, scrolls down multiple times, waits for the tweets to load, and extracts the new tweets. It keeps doing this until there arent any other tweets. the `parse_tweets` function is now called with selector instead of `selector.xpath()`, since we are passing in individual tweet nodes. Sorry this is my first post and of course I had to make it a novel.. ps dont forget to delete `page.query_selector_all("//article[@data-testid='tweet']")` from your for loop

```
def scrape_tweet(url: str, page: Page):
    # go to url
    page.goto(url)
    #wait for content to load
    page.wait_for_selector("//article[@data-testid='tweet']")
    tweets = []
    while True:
        prev_tweet_count = len(tweets)
        for i in range(2):  #make the range as long as needed
            page.mouse.wheel(0, 15000)
            page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
            new_tweets = page.query_selector_all("//article[@data- 
               testid='tweet']")
            for tweet in new_tweets[len(tweets):]:
                html = tweet.inner_html()
                selector = Selector(text=html)
                tweet_data = parse_tweets(selector)[0]
                tweets.append(tweet_data)
            if len(tweets) == prev_tweet_count:
                # no more new tweets loaded
                break
    return tweets
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the i loop in the above? Not the contents, but why is the i loop needed as well as the while True loop?